# Eclipse: Upload eclipse settings automatically

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I often configure my eclipse with

- customized perspectives
- customized editor and other settings
- etc.

Q1. Is there any feature by which this eclipse settings gets uploaded automatically to some cloud periodically so that I won't loose these settings in case I forgot to do this manually?

Q2. Is this requirement something desired by many developers and if so then how most developers deals with it?

Answer (score 0):

There is such a service emerging at Eclipse:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_USS

And the Oomph technology in the upcoming Eclipse Neon release could use that service to store those preferences and re-create your preferences across installations and workspaces. This wiki contains a lot of additional information about Oomph:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer

Hope this helps!!!